# Help creating crontab to help with Disk Space Management IE: Delete files over 1 week old

Tags: scripts, disk-management

I need a script I can call in crontab that equates out to ---

```
 find all files < 1 week old | rm files.
```

I use macrium reflect free edition to back up my windows machines to a samba share dedicated to macrium. But the free edition doesn't come with the ability to delete files older then a week and therefor my drive will eventually fill up or require constant monitoring. I would like to learn how to do this, not just to continue using free Reflect (It's so good I'm just waiting till I can afford a 4 pack @ 140$) but so I can use it for other purposes as well. Any Ideas?

Its tricky because It cant say anything older then April 5th, as that's useless in a week, it needs to be a mathematical equation in the command like, find all files < 1 week old | rm files.

Thanks for your time...

Donut

Comment: While this solved my problem, it would not have been hard to enter the one line of code, but I APPRECIATE your time finding this, I do know how to use google, and I searched for my specific parameters and to vague parameters. I wonder if I could change the wording of question so others would find this post easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```